# Nvidia Higher Resolution becomes bright and grainy

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, resolution, brightness

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I'd like to use the higher resolutions, but when I do the display becomes annoyingly bright and grainy. I can confirm it happens on the Geforce 610 and higher models. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set not native resolution for LCD monitor, the quality can't be  good.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Nvidia-settings` from a dash or terminal

```
Nvidia-settings
```

Choose your display under the `GPU` section and here you can adjust gamma and brightness, amongst other stuff, to your liking

[image]